# ¿Cómo eliminar elementos creados de forma dinámica?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.7

tengo un problema para eliminar/ocultar widgets en tkinter creados dinámicamente. Esa funcion genera los resultados de una busqueda en tkinter, el problema es que se acumulan unos sobre otros. La idea es que cada vez que se ejecute la función elimine los labels creados por la anterior ejecución si la hubo. He intentado usar el método pack_forget() excepto si saltaba la excepción NameError y solo elimina el último label (la búsqueda a veces crea más de uno). No sé si se podrá eliminar todos los labels. He intentado poniéndole un bucle for al pack_forget, pero sigue eliminando solo uno. No sé si por nombre de elemento (todos los labels llevan ese nombre, label) se podrá eliminar del tirón. Muchas gracias

````
def funcion():
    try:
        label.pack_forget()
    except:
        pass
    for i,url in enumerate(resultados_lista):
        v=tk.StringVar()
        tabName=tabControl.select()
        textWidget = tabControl.nametowidget(tabName)
        global label
        label=tk.Label(textWidget,textvariable=v, cursor="hand2")
        v.set(url)
        f = font.Font(label, label.cget("font"))
        f.configure(underline=True)
        label.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
        label.after(60000, label.pack_forget)
        label.bind("<Button-1>",lambda e,url=url:abrir_resultado(url))```
````

Comment: Si crees que tu solución puede ser útil a más personas, te sugiero eliminar el comentario y convertirlo en respuesta, donde tienes más espacio para explicarte y dejar bien legible el código. Incluso (pasado un tiempo) puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, ahora lo cambio

Comment: intenta con destroy pero debes saber el nombre del widget
tambien puedes revisar la clase del widget con winfo class widget Por ejemplo si el widget es Label, que se destruya.

Answer (score 0):

Antes del bucle se crea un `labelframe`:

```
group = tk.LabelFrame(tab1, text="Resultados", padx=10, pady=10)
group.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)
```

... y en vez de usar `label.pack_forget()` se usa `label.master.destroy()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hay un método que es Winfo children, el cual en TCL, por lo menos, devuelve un listado de los widgets, que son hijos, o están anidados, a un widget principal.

POr ejemplo, uno puede anidar widget a un canvas, o a un text, a un panedwindow a un frame o a un Toplevel, o a la ventana general.

Entonces dependiendo quien es el padre de los widgets, una vez sepas cuál widget es que necesitas cerrar, normalmente en TCL se haría con un foreach

```
   foreach {h} [winfo children .m] { destroy $h}
```

En python pienso que se puede hacer una función, que dado el nombre del widget como argumento, lo destruya, lo configure o lo mueva a otra parte fuera de la pantalla, Tkinter puede mover ventanas fuera de las coordenadas máximas de la pantalla. O los ponga transparentes, para que no se muestren.

Los MensageBox o los cuadros Como ColorChoose, ChooseFont, o la Consola, no hacen parte del entorno tkinter porque son creados directamente por el Sistema OPerativo, la única forma es revisando las tareas del Sistema Operativo, por lo que no se pueden ver por el método Winfo, porque no son registrados como ventanas del Constructor.

Es mejor no crearlos indiscriminadamente ni dinámicamente, porque solo se pueden cerrar con la X de la ventana o con el botón que traen por defecto para cerrarla, lo único es que podrías generar un evento que mueva el mouse con event_generate wrap encima del botón de la X de la ventana y generar el clic para que cierre.